# Prime numbers up to a certain number

Tags: php, primes

here is the problem, i need to find prime numbers up to a certain number and here is my code:

```
$a = 56;

for($i = 2; $i<=$a; $i++)
{
    if($i == 2)
    {
        echo "2</br>";
    }

    if($i == 3)
    {
        echo "3</br>";
    }

    if($i == 5)
    {
        echo "5</br>";
    }

    if($i == 7)
    {
        echo "7</br>";
    }

    for($j =3; $j <= ceil($i/2); $j = $j + 2)
    {
        if($i % 2 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if($i % 3 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if($i % 5 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if($i % 7 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$i</br>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it kinda seems like a brute force algorithm, doesnt it? Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks for help!!!

Comment: A bit...you can start throwing out numbers you know for sure aren't prime (such as evens)

Comment: Have a look at the various [prime sieves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes).

Comment: Take a look at the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). There are also some other algorithms to get prime numbers.

Comment: is that source code perl?

Comment: I think it is PHP actually. The questioner should place the tag of the language used.

Comment: The source code is PHP

Comment: This is not brut force it is hardcode force :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose x is the limit (till which you want prime number)..

```
for($n=2;$n<=$x;$n++)
{
  $i=2; 
  while($i<=$n-1) 
  {
    if($n % $i == 0)
    break;
    $i++;
  }
  if($i==$num) 
  echo $n;   // $n is the prime number...
}
```

Comment: @pzaenger Yeah.. You are right.. Actually I wrote it directly.. so, I forgot $ symbol.. :P

Comment: While this works, it is an inefficient algorithm (`O(n^2)` - will quickly slow down for large `$n`).  A quick way to improve it is to only loop up to `sqrt($n)`, since if `$n % $i == 0` then `$n % ($n / $i)` will also be zero, and either `$i` or `$n / $i` will be `<= sqrt($n)`.  A better, but more complicated algorithm is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  There are others under the Wikipedia article [Generating primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes).